# flot order bars not working with multiple legends

Tags: jquery, flot

I am trying to have multiple legends on a single xaxis point but it is not working properly. https://jsfiddle.net/shorif2000/fhpsr0qk/

All the legends have same value which does not make sense.

```
var datasets = [{
  "label": "Technology Operations",
  "data": [
    [5, 78],
    [6, 18],
    [7, 29],
    [8, 61],
    [9, 186],
    [10, 247],
    [11, 55],
    //[null, 19],
    [0, 34],
    [1, 14],
    [2, 26],
    [3, 39],
    [4, 60]
  ],
  "bars": {
    "order": 1
  }
}];
```

Comment: You have the same `data` for all labels. I've altered some values [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/g4tfz1c7/). See the changes

Comment: @Raviteja Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @Raidri I thought it was a simple issue, so posted as comment. Now I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same `data` for all labels.

I've changed some values:

```
 {
  "label": "ANOC",
  "data": [
    [5, 10],
    [6, 18],
    [7, 29],
    [8, 61],
    [9, 186],
    [10, 247],
    [11, 55],
   // [null, 19],
    [0, 10],
    [1, 14],
    [2, 26],
    [3, 39],
    [4, 60]
  ],
  "bars": {
    "order": 2
  }
```

[**Fiddle Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/g4tfz1c7/)